# Oracle 11g: Pass array as input parameter to an oracle stored procedure using simple jdbc call

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, oracle11g

I have the following stored proc:

```
PROCEDURE test( p_a IN VARCHAR_ARRAY, p_b VARCHAR_ARRAY, p_c IN VARCHAR_ARRAY, 
p_d VARCHAR_ARRAY , p_e NUMBER_ARRAY,  p_f IN NUMBER_ARRAY, p_Results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
```

where

```
TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
type VARCHAR_ARRAY IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Now, I'm trying to call this proc from java using `SimpleJdbcCallOperations`.

```
SimpleJdbcCallOperations jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withSchemaName(schema)
                .withCatalogName(catalog);
final Result result = (Result) response.results().get(Constants.Dal.RESULTS);
final RowMapper<T> rowMapper = result.mapper();
jdbcCall.returningResultSet(Constants.Dal.RESULTS, rowMapper);
SqlParameterSource in = new SqlParameterSource();
in.addValue("p_a", new SqlArrayValue(a), Types.ARRAY, "VARCHAR_ARRAY");
in.addValue("p_b", new SqlArrayValue(b), Types.ARRAY, "VARCHAR_ARRAY");
in.addValue("p_c", new SqlArrayValue(c), Types.ARRAY, "VARCHAR_ARRAY");
in.addValue("p_d", new SqlArrayValue(d), Types.ARRAY, "VARCHAR_ARRAY");
in.addValue("p_e", new SqlArrayValue(e), Types.ARRAY, "NUMBER_ARRAY");
in.addValue("p_f", new SqlArrayValue(f), Types.ARRAY, "NUMBER_ARRAY");

final List<T> results = (List<T>) jdbcCall.executeObject(response.clazz(), in);
```

where a,b,c,d are String[] and e,f are BigDecimal[]

But I get the following error:

> CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call
>   test(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17059];
>   Fail to convert to internal representation:
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@5dadd44e; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@5dadd44e"

I've tried many combinations.. using List<> instead of [] and double instead of BigDecimal, different Types, ... Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Types are declared inside stored proc. and i tried adding params by specifying the schema, package name, like this: `in.addValue("p_a", new SqlArrayValue(a), Types.ARRAY, "SCHEMANAME.PACKAENAME.VARCHAR_ARRAY");`

Oracle version : 11.2.0.3.0 (11g)

@Lukas Eder mentioned in comment that only 12c supports Associative arrays. How do I achieve this in 11g?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using? Because prior to 12c, you cannot bind associative arrays to JDBC anyway...

Comment: Are those types declared at schema level (i.e. using `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ...`) or are they declared within a package?

Comment: @LukeWoodward  - It's in procedure, but i tried adding params by specifying the schema, package name, like this: 
`in.addValue("p_a", new SqlArrayValue(a), Types.ARRAY, "SCHEMANAME.PACKAENAME.VARCHAR_ARRAY");`

Comment: @LukasEder - I'm using 11.2.0.3.0 .. (11g) . How do I achieve the same in 11g?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Have to **convert the Java Arrays to Oracle native Arrays** before passing them:

```
MapSqlParameterSource inParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();    
try {
    DataSource ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
    Connection conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
    if (conn.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class))
        oracleConnection = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

    ARRAY aArrayValue = oracleConnection.createARRAY("VARCHAR_ARRAY", a.toArray());
    ARRAY bArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("VARCHAR_ARRAY", b.toArray());
    ARRAY cArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("VARCHAR_ARRAY", c.toArray());
    ARRAY dArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("VARCHAR_ARRAY", d.toArray());
    ARRAY eArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("NUMBER_ARRAY", e.toArray());
    ARRAY fArray = oracleConnection.createARRAY("NUMBER_ARRAY", f.toArray());

    inParams.addValue("p_a", aArrayValue);
    inParams.addValue("p_b", bArray);
    inParams.addValue("p_c", cArray);
    inParams.addValue("p_d", dArray);
    inParams.addValue("p_e", eArray);
    inParams.addValue("p_f", fArray);

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It's very important to add to the answer that you need always to close your datasource connection for returning it back to the pool connection! `conn.close();` Otherwise, you will get connection leak!